# Downloading a file from sourceforge [i.e No specific file name]

Tags: java, sourceforge

I want to make an installer for my project. I know how to do this, but only when I have the specific name of the file on the web page that I wish to download. Sourceforge can automatically find the latest download, but how can I get this file through use of Java? Thanks.

If you need it, project downloads link is here [Not the automatic download]: https://sourceforge.net/projects/herobrawl/files/?source=navbar

Thanks again guys,

I appreciate all help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm gonna show you how to do it with HTML parsing. **But** if the SourceForge API supports this feature, it would be better to do it with the SourceForge API.

To run this code you will need [JSOUP](http://jsoup.org/)

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    System.out.println("Parsing the download page...");
    //Get the versions page
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://sourceforge.net/projects/herobrawl/files/").get();
    //Every link to the download page has class "name"
    Elements allOddFiles = doc.select(".name");
    //Elements are sorted by date, so the first element is the last added
    Element lastUploadedVersion = allOddFiles.first();
    //Get the link href
    String href = lastUploadedVersion.attr("href");
    //Download the jar
    System.out.println("Parsing done.");
    System.out.println("Downloading...");
    String filePath = downloadFile(href, "newVersion.jar");
    System.out.println("Download completed. File saved to \"" + filePath + "\"");
}

/**
 * Downloads a file
 *
 * @param src The file download link
 * @param fileName The file name on the local machine
 * @return The complete file path
 * @throws IOException
 */
private static String downloadFile(String src, String fileName) throws IOException {
    String folder = "C:/myDirectory";//change this to whatever you need
    //Open a URL Stream
    URL url = new URL(src);
    InputStream in = url.openStream();
    OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(folder + fileName));
    for (int b; (b = in.read()) != -1;) {
        out.write(b);
    }
    out.close();
    in.close();
    return folder + fileName;
}
```